# Magento backend how to set fixed quantity for related products

Tags: magento, configurable-product

Is there a way to set a quantity for related products of a configurable product in Magento ?

I try to explain with a simple example: the shop sell custom bicycles, motorbikes and cars:
- if I choose bicycles then the product will be a list of 1 handlebar, 1 saddle, 2 wheels (e.g.: 1 hard and 1 hard),
- if I choose motobike ... 1 saddle, 2 wheels (e.g.: 1 slick and 1 hard), brakes, engine, ... but also 3 wheels for sidecars
- if I choose car ... 4 wheels (e.g.: 2 slick and 2 hard), ...
How to lock the quantity of related products ? There should be no way to select 3 or 5 wheels for a car ...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: thank you for your suggestion, I was not aware of the existence of magento.stackexange.com, then I'll report there